# Mobilefirst Platform - iPad error - "Invalid response when registering application"

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Current setup - MobileFirst platform 7.1, iOS 9.

After successful iPad build and deployment, when we try opening our application on iPad, we get an error message. Upon further investigation we see the below error message in the JSON response. We have no clue where it is failing and any pointers will be helpful.

> {"responseHeaders":{},"status":200,"responseText":"Invalid response when registering application","invocationContext":null}

Comment: What do you see in the server log from the same timestamp?

Comment: @IdanAdar I don't see a call to the server itself. Something is wrong even before the init is triggered. That's the reason we have no clue.

Comment: Wireshark or tcpdump at the server will tell you clearly what request reached the server and what the response was.

Comment: @Prasath, any updates?

Comment: @idan Adar Is this resolved. I am getting the same when updating the iphone build from 6.1 to 7.1.

Comment: @Prasath, Anu updated on this. We are also getting the same error in iPhone.